# Golang: dealing with binary data

Tags: javascript, go, websocket

I have application client(javascript)-server(golang) and the connection between them are all over websocket. I'm planing using binary messages and i want to create my own protocol for messaging like in this page [protocol](http://agar.gcommer.com/index.php?title=Protocol).

I'm already figure it out in javascript by using DataView but not in golang. Event the primitive data type are similar like they have int8, uint8, int16, uint16 etc, i can't figure it out.

This is the message frame:

```
1      Uint8      opcode
2      Uint16     msg
```

This is the example of javascript code handling the incoming message form websocket with message frame above:

```
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var data = new DataView(evt.data);
    var opcode = data.getUint8(0);
    var msg = data.getUint16(1);
}
```

Can you show me how to do it in golang? i'm using [gorilla websocket](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket). I know that read message are in `[]byte`, but i don't know how to slice it like javascript does with DataView.

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you to use [Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial) or just [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, i already do this with JSON before, but now is optimization phase so i need to switch to binary data. I want the solution with raw binary data like my example in javascript.

Comment: well time to use Flat Buffers https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_go.html

Answer (score 0):

For the uint16 you'll need the binary package. Double-check if LittleEndian is what you want.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
)

func main() {
    a := []byte("yak")

    /* opcode  */ _ = uint8(a[0])
    /* message */ _ = binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(a[1:3])
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/HRu7C5h2a5